# SVG Polligon points to CSS clip-path

Tags: html, css, svg, sass

So I have this svg:

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
viewBox="0 0 995.26 1112.58"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#fff;}</style></defs> 
<title>Artboard 7</title><polygon class="cls-1" points="995.21 335.92 995.21 
335.92 798.61 0 111.04 0 0 189.25 540.15 1112.58 540.19 1112.58 995 336.47 
995 336.46 995.26 336.01 995.21 335.92"/></svg>
```

and I would like to use that shape as a CSS clip-path with percentages but I have no clue on how to convert those points so it works on CSS. Any tool or tricks available to achieve this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I just needed to scale the svg viewbox to (0 0 100 100) and then re calculate the points with that new view bow. eg: the first point would be (995.21 * 100)/995.26